# Clear the Pattern Lock on Android 3.x

Tags: java, android, policy, device-admin, corporate-policy

***What I am doing***

I need to remove (clear) Pattern/ Password/ Pin from device, for corporate policy. I am using   `resetPassword  (String password, int flags)` of  [Device Admin API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html).

*as*

```
public boolean resetPassword(String newPassword) {
        if(ActivityManager.isUserAMonkey()) {
            // Don't trust monkeys to do the right thing!
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.context);
            builder.setMessage("You can't reset my password because you are a monkey!");
            builder.setPositiveButton("I admit defeat", null);
            builder.show();
            return false;
        }
        boolean active = mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdmin);
        if(active) {
            return mDPM.resetPassword(newPassword.trim(), DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

*By calling*

```
resetPassword("");
```

***Problem description***

If Pattern lock is activated on device and OS version is 3.0, 3.1 or 3.2, and I call `resetPassword("")` it gives me a security exception for

`WRTITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` permission. *But this permission can accessible by firmware applications.*

*This issue is discussed at following pages*

[Device Policy Manager - Reset Password - Android 3.0 Problems](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17083)
and
[Device Policy Manager - Reset Password - Android 3.0 Problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085580/device-policy-manager-reset-password-android-3-0-problems)

So, My question is ***how can I clear the Pattern Lock on  3.0, 3.1 or 3.2 versions?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I clear the Pattern Lock on 3.0, 3.1 or 3.2 versions?

You can't, apparently, except as an app installed as part of the firmware.

Comment: And this is because of WRTITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission which requires in above versions, or any other reason?

Comment: @AndroidLearner: Yes, I was referring to that permission. Sorry for not making that clear.